# How to create an associated record within factory girl to pass validations at creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I know very little about FactoryGirl, and have only ever created single-record factories with no associations. Here are two factories I have now for associated models:

```
factory :help_request do
    name "Mrs. Bourque's holiday party"
    description "We need volunteers to help out with Mrs. Bourque's holiday party."
end

factory :donation_item do
    name "20 Cookies"
end
```

Whenever I've needed to associate two records I do it in rspec after the fact with code like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HelpRequest do
  let(:help_request) { FactoryGirl.create(:help_request) }
  let(:donation_item) { FactoryGirl.create(:donation_item) }

  subject { help_request }

  before {
    donation_item.help_request_id = help_request.id
    donation_item.save!
  }
```

Ordinarily this has worked, but now I validate that there is at least one `donation_item` not already marked for destruction:

```
class HelpRequest < ActiveRecord::Base      has_many :events
  has_many :donation_items, dependent: :destroy
  validate :check_donation_items?

  def has_donation_items?
    self.donation_items.collect { |i| !i.marked_for_destruction? }.any?
  end

  def check_donation_items?
    if !has_donation_items?
      errors.add :a_help_request, "must have at least one item."
    end
  end
```

When I run my model test, everything fails with the following:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:help_request) { FactoryGirl.create(:help_request) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: A help request must have at least one item.
```

How can I associate the donation item right in the factory at the time the `help_request` gets created? I see other answers that seem related, but because my understanding of FactoryGirl is so rudimentary, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
factory :donation_item do
    name "20 Cookies"
    help_request
end

factory :help_request do
    name "Mrs. Bourque's holiday party"
    description "We need volunteers to help out with Mrs. Bourque's holiday party."
end
```

Then in your spec:

```
let(:donation_item) { FactoryGirl.create(:donation_item, help_request: FactoryGirl.create(:help_request)) }
```

**Edit**
Do not include `help_request` assocation in the :donation_item factory, and do this in your test:

```
let(:help_request) do
  help_request = build(:help_request)
  help_request.donation_items << build(:donation_item)
  help_request.save!
  help_request
end

subject { help_request }
```

Comment: Also check out the `build` function in the docs: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: When I build it this way, I'm getting the following error: `Failure/Error: subject { help_request }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method 'help_request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HelpRequest:0x007ffbb451a380>
`

Comment: Did you update your `donation_item` factory as I've showed above?

Comment: Actually, with that association in the factory you can even have this in the spec (without explicitly setting help_request): let(:donation_item) { FactoryGirl.create(:donation_item) }.. it's already doing that in the factory. See "Associations" section in the doc I references

Comment: In your donation_item.rb model, does it "belong_to :help_request"?

Comment: Yes. It does: `belongs_to :help_request`. I tried it with your original statement (declaring the `help_request` along with the `donation_item`) and without (just declaring the `donation_item`) and in both cases, I get the error on `subject { help_request }`

Comment: I've edited the answer to build and associate prior to creating `help_request`. Another thought - are you sure your "has_donation_items?" method is doing what you want? If ANY donation items are not marked_for_destruction, it will return false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101419/discussion-between-tobogranyte-and-mikeorr85).